# How can i output divide sign through php

Tags: php, html

I've seen this asked several times, but not with a good resolution. How i can output this (÷) divide sign through php?

When I try to echo this its outputting this symbol �.

Comment: Make sure you're using utf-8

Comment: I'm already using utf-8 in header

Comment: you have to use (/) inplace of (÷)

Comment: @kruti he is not using that to calculate..

Comment: Then make sure your php script file is utf-8

Comment: The headers for character encoding, the meta charset tag and the actual character encoding of your document must match.

Comment: As an aside, the character “÷” means division to some people, subtraction to some other, and nothing to many other. So are you sure you want to use it instead of a more unambiguous symbol?

Comment: Who uses “÷” as a subtraction symbol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<span>&#247;</span>
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/index.htm

Comment: Of `&#xF7;` - personally I prefer hex codes than decimal numbers.

Comment: While this solves the specific case, it hides the symptoms of a more fundamental problem: there is something wrong with character encoding settings.